# Make new tab always be the rightmost one (at the end of all tabs)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I haven't been updating Visual Studio Code for a while and now I finally did. The unpleasant surprise was that it started opening new tabs after the *current* one instead of the *last* open one (which was the way it had acted before I updated it). 
 I've searched through the options and still can't find how to turn it off. 
Is there a way to do that?

I'm on OSX if the behavior differs from Win/Linux.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> // Controls where editors open. Select 'left' or 'right' to open
>   editors to the left or right of the current active one. Select 'first'
>   or 'last' to open editors independently from the currently active one.

```
"workbench.editor.openPositioning": "last",
```

The default is "right" which is the behavior you do not want.  Try "last".

Comment: The rule for these comments is to avoid using them for "thanks", etc... But, still I felt the urge to thank you so very much for this post! The behavior of VS.Code was bothering me for months, and finally I decided to google it, and your reply was the second one I read, and voila: it's magically corrected... :D